# File encoding error in Python 3.6 with "UTF8" charset

Tags: xml, python-3.x, csv, character-encoding

I receive an XML file with `incoming orders` encoded in UTF8:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Beleg xmlns="http://www.mauve.eu/MauveXml/2.0/"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mauve.eu/MauveXml/2.0/ http://download.mauve.eu/schema/MauveXml_2_0.xsd"
>
```

And I run a Python 3.6 script to transform this XML file to a CSV file.
In the script the command is

```python
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(xmlfile, encoding = 'utf-8'), 'xml')
```

and 98% of the times the complete script is working fine.

But, with some of the XML files it doesn't work until I manually change a text character like: `ğ`, `ě` etc.

The error is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Modification Python Scripts\Python Script23\test5\New Folder\xmlconvert-final.py", line 180, in <module>
    convertXMLtoCSV(xmlfile,path)
  File "C:\Modification Python Scripts\Python Script23\test5\New Folder\xmlconvert-final.py", line 152, in convertXMLtoCSV
    outputwriter.writerow(i)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u202d' in position 83: character maps to <undefined>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: '\u202d' is Unicode LEFT-TO-RIGHT OVERRIDE, not `"╩"`

Comment: U+202D is not the character that you are showing, it is the [Left-to-right Direction Override](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202d/index.htm). I'd like to see a full working example, including an XML file that throws this error.

Comment: @Duncan [link](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202d/index.htm) in the encodings section it's  `How to type in Microsoft Windows Alt +202D`

Comment: Edited and removed that mistake. 
@usr2564301 i can't publish the XML file, it's private data, not for public display. What do you mean by working example? 
In all the rest XML files the script works great as meant to.

Comment: The character you showed in Windows is character 202 in the codepage 437. In Unicode that would be character  `"\u2569"`. What happened was that your Alt key sequence took only the 202 and ignore the rest. Anyway the point is that you have a character u202d which is giving you problems.

Comment: I'm not asking for private data but for something we can *test* on *our* computers. You are referring to "an" XML file on which you use "your script". That is not much to go on for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the traceback you'll see that the error is occurring in `cp1252.py` from which we can deduce you are writing the CSV file using codepage 1252.

The character that is giving you problems is a pretty unusual unicode character and doesn't exist in any form in that codepage. That's why it is giving you an error: there is no way to encode the left to right direction override into codepage 1252.

When you open the csv file you can specify an explicit encoding. If you don't have to use cp1252 then try explicitly setting it to `utf-8` as that will accept any unicode text. If you do have to use cp1252 then set the `errors` parameter on the open call to ignore or replace the encoding errors. For example `errors='replace'` will replace the bad character with a question mark:

```
with open('output_file_name', 'w', newline='', errors='replace') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow('my_utf8_string')
```

Possible settings for `errors` are:

- 'strict': raise an exception in case of an encoding error
- 'replace':
  replace malformed data with a suitable replacement marker, such as
  '?' or '\ufffd'
- 'ignore': ignore malformed data and continue without
  further notice
- 'xmlcharrefreplace': replace with the appropriate XML
  character reference (for encoding only)
- 'backslashreplace': replace
  with backslashed escape sequences (for encoding only)

In general when encoding unicode you should attempt to use utf-8 or utf-16 as they will allow you to encode everything without errors. Using any other encoding you may encounter characters than cannot be encoded so if you have to use a different encoding you must be prepared to handle those errors.

Comment: This is the code i had:
`outputFile = open(filename, 'w', newline='', errors='replace')
 outputwriter = csv.writer(outputFile)`  
so, i just added the " errors='replace'" and now the script is working with that XML file too. Thank you very much @Duncan